# dplyr: Create a new variable as a function of all existing variables without defining their names

Tags: r, dplyr

In the following dataframe I want to create a new variable as the following function of all existing ones:

```
as.numeric(paste0(df[i,],collapse=""))
```

However, I don't want to define the column names explicitly because their number and names maybe different each time. How can I do that using dplyr?

The equivalent in base r would be something like this:

```
apply(df,1,function(x) as.numeric(paste0(x,collapse="")))


df <- structure(list(X1 = c(50, 2, 2, 50, 5, 5, 2, 50, 5, 5, 50, 2, 
5, 5, 50, 2, 2, 50, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), X2 = c(2, 50, 5, 5, 50, 
2, 5, 5, 50, 2, 2, 50, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 50, 2, 2, 50, 5, 5), 
    X3 = c(5, 5, 50, 2, 2, 50, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 50, 2, 2, 50, 
    5, 5, 2, 50, 5, 5, 50, 2), X4 = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 50, 2, 
    2, 50, 5, 5, 2, 50, 5, 5, 50, 2, 5, 5, 50, 2, 2, 50)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Is `df %>% mutate(newcol=as.numeric(do.call(paste0,df)))` what you are looking for? Anyway, the equivalent in `base` R is not what you have indicated, but `as.numeric(do.call(paste0,df))` (much more efficient).

Comment: Yes , thank you! You can use . instead of df inside paste: df %>% mutate(newcol=do.call(paste0,.)). I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df %>% mutate(newcol=as.numeric(do.call(paste0,df)))
```

Or (as you suggested, maybe more `dplyr` style):

```
df %>% mutate(newcol=as.numeric(do.call(paste0,.)))
```